# Negotiating salary for junior position - software dev

Tags: software-industry, salary, software-development, junior, romania

I am soon to graduate (one month) and I'm going to have an interview with the HR and the manager of the team (final stage of the recruitment process, I've passed the technical tests) in a cool company.
As far as I know I will be asked about my salary expectations (among other things).
As far as I find on the internet the salaries vary between 5.5 - 6k RON to 8k RON, and a friend of mine who had an offer from the company (other team) received an offer of 8k RON (even though he asked for far less - he has a tendency to underestimate himself).
Now, the point is that I am not really willing to lower the bar below 7k, but I also really like them. Some points why I think that 7k is my right value at the moment:

- The position is Junior, but I had two internships before, totalling 6
  months. They don't ask for prior experience. My other friend had a
  year long internship.
- I've had offers for 7k before from companies that I liked - and didn't even have to negotiate, it is just what I asked for.
- I've interviewed with 4 teams in total, so they should have a
  comprehensive view of my skills. They also added one more team to the
  process because I have some rare skills (apart from those required
  for this position), that are related to that other position.
- I nailed all the interviews apart from some questions (another team) on a topic that I said in advance that I don't master (even before scheduling an interview with that team).
- The interview for this particular position seemed easy to me - I could have answered far tougher questions.
- I have a history (as an intern) to deliver much more than expected from me - even gaining exposure to higher level managers (not even from my country) and the department showing my project to other departments - and they know it.

  **Does it make sense to raise these points when negotiating?** 7k is about 1.5k more than the mean salary for junior in this city, and there is a scarcity in work force (I am also significantly more skilled than the usual graduate)?
  I could be honest and tell them that I want a long stay at their company, but if they received an offer in 4 months valuing 15-20% more than their actual salary, what would they do, even considering how much they like their current workplace? I'd actually be amazed if this didn't happen for me. **Can I put the problem this way? Does it sounds rude?**
  **Lastly, but not least, do you think that my expectations are unrealistic?**

Comment: What salary range did the company list on the job posting?

Comment: They didn't. This is not US or Germany where (I think) they have to.

Comment: @DorinIonita - Companies in the US are not required to list a salary range when they advertise an opening.

Comment: I'm sorry for my above comment, I shouldn't have named any country while I am not sure about the legislation. What I was actually trying to say is that that I know there are *some* countries that enforce salary listing by law, but not mine.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, companies pay what they want to pay for a junior position.   You may claim experience, but realistically, you're trying to get your first position in the field.    There just isn't room for a lot of negotiation.

Having said that, try to let them make the first move.   THey ask what you want, ask them what it pays.    Don't offer up first amount first, if you can help it.

THEN...if they offer a lowball amount, yes--by all means bring up the past qualifications, make the case for why you are not the average new college grad and why you believe you're worth more.    It can't hurt to say "I've done this and this and this and this and this.....and I'm ready to step in and hit the ground running."

Good luck.    If nothing else, you are there for a time, getting your experience, and then you cash in on the next job.

Comment: I am not sure that I know how to make them tell the number first. Anyway, thanks a lot, it is helpful.

Comment: Just ask...."Is there a standard range of salary that the position pays?"    "Is there a figure you had in mind?"

Comment: How do you avoid giving the first number? If they keep insisting that you need to give them a number, should I be giving them the silent treatment?

Comment: At some point, someone has to speak first.  Just saying it's best to avoid being that person if at all possible.

Comment: +1. Don't be afraid to negotiate your pay. After deciding they want you hire you, they won't change their minds if you ask for more money (unless you come across as rude and unreasonable). If they say "6", you can politely say, "I believe I am worth 7.5 and I know you'll agree when you see my work."  The worst they can do is say, "no, we only have budget for 6". And they'll respect you for standing up for yourself. It means you'll stand up for the company when they need it.